# Who can send me an example of an XML embedded schema?

Tags: xml, schema

I understand xml schema import/include, I can define the schema in another file and re-use in current WSDL or schema. But I still don't understand what is the Embedded schema, I even cannot search one keyword "embedded" in one schema.

Could you guys can sent one "Embedded" schema example, I can understand and study it?

Comment: Yes, I had asked somebody to make one embedded schema for me, it simply to create, just copy one schema file into one schema or wsdl file, this will be called inline schema/embedded schema

Comment: If by "embedded" schema you mean a schema embedded within the source document it describes, they are not widely used or supported, and are not very useful. What problem are you trying to solve to which you see embedded schemas as the solution?

Comment: Thanks Michael. I am just get deep into Schema. Our product support import, include and embedded schema, so this is why I raised the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We only need to put schema inline along with WSDL, this will be called embbed schema.

Thanks everyone.